# Is it possible to shield a metal ball with electrostatic shielding, or any other way?

Tags: shielding, electrostatic, metal

Is it possible to shield a metal ball by the electrostatic shielding such that metal ball doesn't suffer electrostatic induction?

There is an electric field present near the metal ball but I want that this metal ball doesn't induce charges on it by electrostatic induction. Is there any way to do that?

For example, let say there is an hollow metal sphere which inner walls are insulted and an electrolyte is filled in that metal hollow sphere. This all setup is placed in external electric field. So, *is there will be polarization in electrolyte? *

Answer (score 1):

Any ungrounded metal thing between the charged source and the ball will tend to become charged and then become a source that would tend to charge the ball. A grounded thing would share the charge it receives with the earth and mostly prevent the ball from being charged. It would most effective at preventing the ball from being charged if it is larger than both the source and the ball. The most effective aspect of the size would be the area, thus a large flat thing would be more effective as a shield than a ball that is not so large.

Electrostatic induction by itself does not charge a nearby object. A charged object that is brought near another object only attracts or repels electrons or positive ions that can move in that object. If a conductor is connected to a more distant point on the second object the electrons can be repelled through that conductor to a third object or to earth. If the conductor is then disconnected, the second object is then left with a deficit of electrons and a positive charge.

Shielding an object from any influence of a nearby charged object can be accomplished by providing something between the object and the charged object that can effectively redirect that influence by providing a place for charge redistribution that allows electrons to flow to a place like the earth that can absorb an "infinite" number of electrons without much charge imbalance.

Comment: I need that there should not be any charge redistribution on the metal ball which is present in electric field. How to do that?

Comment: Put a big sheet of conductive material between the ball and the nearby charge. The required size of the shield depends on the strength and extent of the nearby charge and how completely free of charge the shielded ball must be.

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding

Comment: I have added to my answer.  With regard to electrolyte, if there is an imbalance of charge from one part of the sphere to another, I think the electrolyte would be polarized for as long as the imbalance persists. I think that paragraph is less understand able and a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to shield a metal ball by the electrostatic shielding such that metal ball doesn't suffer electrostatic induction?

Yes. The link below, Lec 05: Electrostatic Shielding (Faraday Cage) | 8.02 Electricity and Magnetism (Walter Lewin), is a video showing that a charged metal "bucket" with top opening does not transfer charge to a metal ball inserted into the cavity of the "bucket". This means a static electric field outside the metal "bucket" does not transfer to the inside cavity.

The time index begins with some theory and within maybe ten minutes there is the classroom demonstration:

https://youtu.be/79xMsqRp6dE?t=1233

The theory for this result is developed via the assumption that static electric field inside a conductor is zero and the application of Gauss' law.

Answer (score 0):

Conductors self-shield, they are internally electric field-free. So no action is needed.

Charges cannot be "induced". Being an extensive quantity, they can only be transferred via conduction. If no conductor is attached to the ball, again no action is needed.

Comment: Maybe OP means they don't want the charge distribution on the ball to be disturbed?

Comment: If this is the case @AniketKumar then place your to-be-shielded ball into another conducting container without touching it internally. Aka Faraday cage.

Comment: OP did not say that no there is no conductive path to the ball.

Comment: I need that there should not be any charge redistribution on the metal ball due to the electric field.

Comment: "Charges cannot be 'induced.' ...they can only be transferred via conduction." Is false. Charge can be induced in the sense and manner described in the asker's previous question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/605811/charging-by-electrostatic-induction

Comment: @CharlesCowie Please read my answer (and linked questions) carefully. In that question, charges are transferred via the cable in step 3. If you omit step 3, then the last step will get you back to the neutral ball, because **charges cannot be induced**! PS: Ok maybe now I understand that you mean that if you interpret "induce" more generally it could work. I was interpreting it as a noncontact phenomenon like this word is usually meant in electrical / magnetic language.

Comment: Is there will be polarisation on the metal ball which is inside the faraday cage?

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding.